# Question regarding Force on a charged particle in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

We know the force on a charged particle in a magnetic field is given by
$$
{\bf{F}} = q({\bf{v}} \times {\bf{B}})
$$
However, my question is that:
Can this equation be derived?

Comment: Yes, if you take Maxwell's equations as your starting point, for example, as outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force

Comment: Derived from what starting point?

Comment: (I think it is probably best to consider the Lorentz force as a fact about the world, not as something to be "derived," unless you have a specific starting point of interest to you. Given your starting point the "derivation" will likely be a series of equalities, so the derivation can go either way...)

Comment: If you don’t *define* the magnetic field via that equation, how *do* you define it?

Comment: The most fundamental models we have are from the Standard Model, if you do not like postulating the Lorentz force or its Lagrangian you can always start from the Lagrangian of Dirac's equation, force U(1) symmetry, get electromagnetism, take the semiclassical approximation and then see what it looks like in a non-relativistic setting. But I would say that it is too much hard work and it is still postulating a Lagrangian.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, assuming you can accept the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics#Special_relativistic_test_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field)

$$
L = - \frac{m c^2}{\gamma} - q \left(\phi - {\bf v} \cdot {\bf A}\right)
$$

as a starting point, where

$$
\gamma = \left(1 - \frac{{\bf v}^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}
$$

Then apply the [Euler–Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf r}} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf v}} \right)
$$

Note that (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative#Scalar_and_vector_fields))

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf r}} = -q\nabla\left( \phi - {\bf v} \cdot {\bf A} \right) = -q\left[ \nabla\phi -\left({\bf v} \cdot \nabla \right){\bf A} - {\bf v} \times \left(\nabla \times {\bf A}\right)  \right]
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf v}} \right)= \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial {\bf v}}\left( -\frac{m c^2}{\gamma} + q {\bf v} \cdot {\bf A}\right) \right] = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\gamma m {\bf v}\right) + q \frac{d{\bf A}}{dt}
$$

$$
\frac{d{\bf A}}{dt} = \frac{\partial {\bf A}}{\partial t} + \left({\bf v} \cdot \nabla\right) {\bf A}
$$

Putting all of this together, we find

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\gamma m {\bf v}\right) = q\left[- \nabla\phi - \frac{\partial{\bf A}}{\partial t} + {\bf v} \times \left(\nabla \times {\bf A}\right) \right]
$$

or

$$
\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt} = q\left({\bf E} + {\bf v} \times {\bf B} \right)
$$

identifying (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Generalization_to_electrodynamics) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Relativistic))

$$
{\bf p} = \gamma m {\bf v}
$$

$$
{\bf E} = - \nabla\phi - \frac{\partial{\bf A}}{\partial t}
$$

$$
{\bf B} = \nabla \times {\bf A}
$$

Comment: Nice but the Lagrangian is an alternative expression of the Lorentz force itself..

Comment: True, though you could argue that you can get the Lagrangian from requiring that it be a Lorentz scalar. I could update my answer with some links.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from special relativity:
The Newtonian equation ${\bf F}=m{\bf a}$ is not relativistically invariant.
To find a relativistic generalization, we replace $m{\bf a}$ by the relativisitic four-vector $\frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau}$.
For the electromagnetic force on a charged particle we want to write the Lorentz force as a relativistic four-vector that combines the electromagnetic fields with the state of motion of the particle.  The contraction $U_\mu F^{\mu\nu}$ accomplishes this, and then the covariant dynamical equation for a charged particle is
\begin{equation}
\frac{dp^\nu}{d\tau}=qU_\mu F^{\mu\nu}
=\frac{q}{m}p_\mu F^{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
This reduces, in vector notation, to
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dW}{dt}&=& q{\bf v\cdot E}
\label{eq:wte}\\
\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt}&=& 
q\left[{\bf E}+{\bf v\times B}\right].
\label{eq:dpdt2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.

**A.** The Lorentz force can either be taken as basic, a direct expression of experiment, and then use it to define electric and magnetic fields $E$ and $B$.

**B.** Or one can derive it by taking something else as basic.

In the last case one can take the electrostatic force as basic along with the relativistic transformations of electric and magnetic fields.

A point charge $q$, in its rest frame  being inside an electric field $E'$ experiences a force $F'=qE'$.

In a frame of reference that moves with relative velocity $v$ the electric field is transformed as $E'=E+v \times B$ (for a suitable magnetic field $B$)(*) thus the force experienced is $F=q(E+v \times B)$ (assuming $v \lll c$). If electric field $E$ is zero then the magnetic force is $F=q(v \times B)$. QED

(*) See [relativistic transformations of electric and magnetic fields](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity)